# Create Word files from Excel content

Tags: script, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel file that I want to split into several files (Word, PDF is also good), based on content. The content is somewhat like this:

```
Person  Fase  Date       Item  Text
A       1     01-01-2012 Z     Lorem ipsum
A       2     01-02-2012 X     Lorem ipsum
B       1     02-01-2012 Y     Lorem ipsum
C       2     01-01-2012 Z     Lorem ipsum
```

I want Word/PDF documents with names like

```
Person_Fase.docx
```

And as content the date, item and text. Idealy in a table layout. Any hints/ clues on how to get there? It's about 700 clients, with up to 300 Excel entries each.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can use open office. After opening the xls file with open office, Click the export under the Menu then export it as pdf or docx.

Comment: Then how do I make a file per person/fase? I am aware of the save as option ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is an Add-In for Microsoft Word which performs this exact function using a Mail Merge.

Go to http://www.gmayor.com/individual_merge_letters.htm, read the instructions carefully and download the zip file of templates.

Install the template for the version of Word that you have.  I have used this in Word 2010, but it looks like other versions are also supported.

In your Excel spreadsheet, create a new column with your desired filename.  For example =A2&"="&B2 if Person were in column A and Fase was in column B.

In Word, create a new document using the new template.

Then start a Mail Merge using your Excel spreadsheet as a data source.

Format the doument as you wish, probably by inserting a table with five columns and two rows.  In the first row put your column headers and in the second row insert the Merge Fields.

Click Split the Merge and go through the wizard to select the records, choose the filename, and set your path.

This saves each record/row in a separate Word document, using the filename and path you set.